# Rest Api testing using Rest Assured - Not Working

Tags: rest, rest-assured

I'm working on Rest API Testing using Rest Assured and i've coded properly but don't know what happening displaying proper request but in server request is displaying as null for each and every input parameter.

Code:

```
public class ValidateCardAPI {

    public Response validatecardTest(String cardNo, Object mobileNo, String code, String progType) {

        ValidateCard validateCard = new ValidateCard();

        validateCard.setCardNo(cardNo);
        validateCard.setMobileNo(mobileNo);
        validateCard.setcCode(code);
        validateCard.setProgmType(progType);

        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(validateCard);
        System.out.println(jsonObject);

        RequestSpecification requestSpecification = RestAssured.given();

        requestSpecification.contentType("application/json");
        requestSpecification.accept("application/json");
        requestSpecification.body(jsonObject);

        Response response = requestSpecification.post("http://ipaddress:port/request url");

        System.out.println(response);
        return response;

    }

     public static void main(String args[]) throws JSONException {

     ValidateCardAPI validateCardapi= new ValidateCardAPI(); 
     Response resStatus =validateCardapi.validatecardTest("XXXXXXXXXX",null,"2222","C");
     String body = resStatus.getBody().asString(); System.out.println(body);

     JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(body); String resvalue =
     jsonObj.getString("errorMessage");

      System.out.println(resvalue);

      if(resvalue.equalsIgnoreCase("SUCCESS")) {

      System.out.println("Validate Card APi Response is ="+resvalue);

      }else {
      System.out.println("Validate Card APi Response is Fail becasue ="+resvalue);
      }   

      }
```

Please any one provide help in case i'm doing any wrong.

Comment: provide more information, what error your are getting in console?

Comment: Getting internal server error in response

Comment: ISE have nothing to do with Rest-Assured, make sure you are hitting correct end point cross check your (/)slash in your end point. use below line to debug rest-assured request            
 //RestAssured.given().log().all();

Comment: I've tried  RestAssured.given().log().all(); and displaying as io.restassured.internal.RequestSpecificationImpl@5aa9e4eb line,i'm i missing any code

Comment: it is just for logging, so that you can see what is going on behind the scene just change your 11th line (in your code which you posted above)to  RequestSpecification requestSpecification = RestAssured.given().log().all(); then check console carefully.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    // convert body in string
    requestSpecification.body(jsonObject.toString());
    if you have any authorisation header, please add as 
    requestSpecification.header("request_id", "request_id value");
    requestSpecification.header("data2", "data value"); 

and make sure you post URL is currect
```

Comment: Thank you ,i will try this once.Actually i've used your video tutorial code only.

Comment: Thank you ,this solution fixed my issue,Thank you so much and tell me why jsonObject to String();